# Getting a sub string between two different delimiters

Tags: php, trim, strpos

I am trying to "extract" the link part from a tweet message:

`$tweet = "Testing a tweet with a link https://t.co/h4C0aobVnK in the middle"`

I have a function which doesn't quite work but I'm not sure why. I need to get the link part, so I need everything between `https://` and the `space`

**The result I want** would be: `t.co/h4C0aobVnK`

This is the function:

```
function dataBetween($string, $start, $end){
    $sp = strpos($string, $start)+strlen($start);
    $ep = strpos($string, $end)-strlen($start);
    $data = trim(substr($string, $sp, $ep));
    return trim($data);
}
```

Here's how it's called:

```
$link = dataBetween($tweet,'https://',' ');
```

But **the result I get** is not what I expected:

```
t.co/h4C0aobVnK in the middl
```

Where did I go wrong?

Is there a better way to extract the link part from `$tweet` ? It will always start with https://.

Comment: Do you know what the function does? It's returning exactly as you coded or copied.

Comment: `$ep = strpos($string, $end, $sp)-strlen($start);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use regular expressions for this. This might look complicated, but once you start using them, there is no going back. ;)

```
preg_match_all("/https:\/\/(.*?)\s/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

strpos finds the first occurrence of a string. For $ep, you should start looking AFTER the $sp, not from the beginning of the string

```
$ep = strpos($string, $sp)-strlen($end);
```

also, you could use a regular expression like this |www://([^ ]+)|i
*http is not allowed in the comment box, so just replace ww with that

Answer (score 0):

```
   $ep = strpos($string, $end)-strlen($start);
```

change to

```
$ep = strpos($string, $end)-strlen($end);
```

Just a misstype.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$regex = "((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME

 if(preg_match("/^$regex$/", $tweet , $m))
  var_dump($m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, change this:

```
$ep = strpos($string, $end)-strlen($start);
```

To:

```
$ep = strpos($string, $end, $sp) - strlen($string);
```

Passing the third parameter of [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) (offset) it will start from where the link started, and get the first ' ' after that.

[Working code](https://eval.in/219532)